# run xcode ui test from command line in xcode 8 using swift 2.3

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

i use this command to run my xcode build ui test from terminal:

```
xcodebuild -workspace test.xcworkspace \
-scheme "test" \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=ipad Air' \
test
```

but recently i migrated from xcode 7.3 to xcode 8

i use swift 2.3 from

```
use swift legacy version
```

from build setting option.

But when i use the command it shows error and it does not run the ui test.

it works fine, if i run the test without using command line, i mean from project directly, it run the xcode ui test and the terminal command works for xcode 7.3 very nice

the error is

```
error: filename "file.swift" used twice:
 filenames are used to distinguish private declarations with the same name
```

please help how i can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`xcodebuild` natively compiles on swift 3

But you can add a parameter that will let you compile on swift 2.3.
I'm using

```
xcodebuild -toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3 ...other-parameters
```

and it works perfectly.

Finally, note that you should pass to swift 3 someday!

Comment: till now the same error shows ...... it can build but if i use the "test"  , it can not succeed , error is the same .... see the error in question

Comment: ah... there must be a second problem. Anyway you should tell xcodebuild which version of swift to compile. It seems you have a problem with your "test" target. According to the error message, the "file.swift" is used twice. Try to search "file.swift in you project manager to see if you have a duplicate. If no, try to remove "file.swift" and import it again.